# Why did Kenobi alert Grievous about ship's self-destruct?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* Season 5 Episode 8 *Bound for Rescue*, Grievous defeated Kenobi & gained control over his Republic starship. Moments before he was going to collect data from data banks of ship, a holographic message of Kenobi appeared saying that the ship was about to self-destruct.

What was the point of alerting Grievous when he could be killed silently?

When it comes to diverting him from data stealing, I think killing Grievous was more important than saving some tactical data. It could change the wind of The Clone Wars.
Plus, the message wasn't that effective to save data if data security was poor enough to be broken within seconds. B1 Battle Droids already had orders after all.

Why didn't Kenobi try killing Grievous silently?

Comment: Without having watched the episode or even most of the series, killing just isn't the Jedi way when they can avoid it.

Comment: @phantom42 :) But, Kenobi did finally kill Grievous in movie. And, according to chats of other Jedi at Jedi Temple, the intention was also killing.. not capturing.

Comment: He also left Anakin to die. That doesn't mean it was his first choice. Especially as a younger, less jaded person, he may have been clinging to his ideals a little bit tighter at the time.

Comment: "I think killing Grievous was more important than saving some tactical data." Maybe Kenobi thought differently.

Comment: @DJClayworth Whatever he thought, it doesn't matter. The alert message wasn't going to contribute in saving data anyway. Read my full question.

Comment: If you're asking about character motivations, his thoughts matter quite a bit.

Comment: Could have also been a gloat move, although that doesn't sound very jedi-like either.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply the [Jedi code](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Code) at work. To be a practitioner of the [Light Side of the Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Light_side_of_the_Force) a Jedi must always act with honor. Even as evil as Grievous was, refusing to tell him that the ship was going to kill him would be dishonorable, and he would no longer be worthy of the Jedi knight. That act simply demonstrates the difference between the Light and Dark sides of the Force. Jedi Code From Wookieoedia:

> It taught its followers to not give in to feelings of anger toward other lifeforms...
>   [Jedi] believed that all lives were precious. The code also forbade the Jedi from killing unarmed opponents as well as seeking revenge.

What possible reason would Ben Kenobi have to allow General Grievous to die in a self-destructing ship? Hatred? Anger? Revenge? Grievous was running away, so he could not let Grievous die out of fear or danger. Kenobi was required to respect his life.

Comment: Can you highlight which point from Jedi code you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Confusing yes, and obviously Grievous couldn't die, even though this would be an excellent opportunity to do so. My only explanation is that Obi-Wan's morality played a part, or he couldn't help besting his greatest foe.

Answer (score -1):

I know he killed him, but I honestly don't think they were trying to have him killed, I think they were trying to arrest him and take him to Coruscant, along with Count Dooku, so they could question them about who the real dark lord was.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure if you're talking about the right episode; obviously General Grievous was _not_ killed, and I'm not sure who "they" are.